# How to obtain list of transactions/activity on metamask

Tags: metamask

How to obtain list of transactions/activity on metamask ?
I'm building an app that interact with metamask, I want to access all of the transactions that is written on metamask from the connected address, but I couldn't find how to do it on metamask documentation. Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

MetaMask doesn't provide accounts' transaction history. The only viable option is to fetch recent transactions through Etherscan API. If you use Ethers.js, you can use the `getHistory` [method](https://docs.ethers.io/v4/cookbook-accounts.html#get-transaction-history):

```
let etherscanProvider = new ethers.providers.EtherscanProvider();

etherscanProvider.getHistory(address).then((history) => {
    history.forEach((tx) => {
        console.log(tx);
    })
});
```

---

Or with ethers v6:

```js
const etherScan = new ethers.EtherscanProvider(network);

/** @type {import('ethers').Transaction[]} */
const history = await etherScan.fetch('account', {
  address: walletAddress,
  action: 'txlist',
});
```